# functions include operation in TWIG how?

Tags: twig

it may insert a web to show in web of me or not?

for me guide and examples for that..

me read above : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

but do not have the result , because of me slow understand .

please help me , thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, can you update it to make it clear what you're trying to do and where it fails?

Comment: me  execute it above wapego.com one where codes twig are supported at version low . so I need support . what I want to do here is to be able to insert another web page  into my page

Comment: Please provide the current code you have in your twig template

Comment: sorry but I do not have any code